# Push key name into an array of object looping over using v-for | Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am aiming to store key names of object I'm looping over with `v-for` in an array within my components data object. I have seen others pass it as props into a separate component, but I instead need to store it in the same component where I'm running my v-for loop.

```html
<div v-for="(fieldData, fieldName, index) in fieldset.fields" :key="`c-form__field--${index + 1}`"></div>
```

I need to push each `fieldName` into an array called `currentFields` in my data object.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [computed method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to do that.

```
computed: {
    // a computed getter
    currentFields: 
      let arr = [];
      this.fieldset.forEach(fields => {
         arr.push(//whatever you need to save)
      });
      return arr;
    }
  }
```